# How can I design a window in Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have creat a QWidget in QMainwindow, but in Forms there is only one mainwindow.ui.
I wonder if I can add a .ui to design my own window?

Answer (score 0):

you should First create your a class that contains a UI file like these :

[image]